# More advanced (free) alternatives to Math3D or Geogebra

Tags: education

I teach vector calculus. I love both Math3D and Geogebra. But I have reached a limit in terms of what these programs can do. Some examples of features that I wish Math3D had:

1. Draw vector fields with color or line weight representing magnitude, rather than length.
2. Draw a slice of a vector field with vectors anchored just along a surface.
3. Copy/paste objects with the same settings (e.g. making a new vector with all the same formatting of a vector I'm already using.)
4. More robust operations (e.g. curl, div, etc.)
5. Parameterize piecewise curves (or logic like "show point P if parameter T > 1, else suppress," etc.)

I could keep going! So I am just looking to upgrade to the next level of software sophistication. I've looked around some, but the lists of visualization software I've found are overwhelming and it's hard to know where to start. Any recommendations?

Comment: If you're looking to use such just for presentation purposes, then although tedious, I think it would be exceedingly beneficial (and a good learning experience to solidify your own knowledge) in the long run to code up some custom software. This would yield the additional benefit of allowing 100% customization to your liking.

Comment: When I need to add labels to Desmos graphs, I export them and use free software like LibreOffice Draw or the Google Drawing on-line equivalent.  That said I don't see a math problem with a strong nexus to your Question, so I'm voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sagemath is free, has roughly the same capabilities of Mathematica, is based on Python, and can be used and shared in the browser: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/

You can see some of the vector calculus tools here: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/vector_calculus/vector_calc_cartesian.html

Comment: Spent last night playing with sagemath. That seems like it will work! I may also be able to get Mathematica through my university, which seems way, way more than adequate as well. I suppose I was looking for something in between sage/mathematica and geogebra/math3D. But having spent a few hours with sage, I've changed my mind and decided it's time just to bite the bullet and learn it! So thanks for the inspiration.